# PHP code won't run - only displaying the content in the file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working with HTML PHP and Ajax for the first time so bear with me. Most of this code is from an example I got online. However, I can't get it to actually INSERT into the database. The ajax function does enter the success function; the success output is just the php file showing as an alert.

I have this all local so I launch chrome as

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files file:///C:/filepath/index2.html
```

I know this isn't good but I'm making do.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Insert</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"> 
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <button type="submit" id="button">SAVE</button>    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){
                var name=$("#name").val();
                var email=$("#email").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'insert.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        name:name,
                        email:email
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   },
                   error:function(data){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                   }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $conn = new mysqli('Azure server URL', 'Username','Password', 'tableName');
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql="INSERT INTO data ('id', 'name', 'email') VALUES (NULL, $name, $email)";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "data inserted";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "failed";
    }
?>
```

Comment: How is your web server configured? How it's handling `php` files?

Comment: Unrelated to what you asked: there is a SQL Injection vulnerability issue in your code.

Comment: You can't directly run php as a local file from the browser. You need a server running that is setup to use the php executable and runs your php file in order to return a result.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values (e.g. right now currently your query would fail if $name or $email don't contain purely numbers!)

Comment: This, combined with the lack of knowledge about how to set up your environment, suggests you are following some really bad tutorial. I highly suggest to buy a reputable book and/or sign up for an accredited course where they might teach you properly. Even if you don't need to worry about things like security now, you don't want to get into bad habits doing things wrong which you then have to spend time unlearning later. The correct way isn't difficult at all. And you certainly need to know how to set up your environment, and how to do basic debugging etc.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, a JS problem, or an HTML problem?

Answer (score 2):

You said

> I have this all local so I launch chrome as
>
> `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files file:///C:/filepath/index2.html`
>
> I know this isn't good but I'm making do.

...not only isn't it good, it's the cause of your problem. Chrome + your filesystem cannot execute PHP code.

You need to use a proper webserver with the PHP runtime available, so it supports executing PHP in response to a HTTP request. It's very easy to use tools such as [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) or [Laragon](https://laragon.org/index.html) to install a full-featured PHP development environment with PHP, Apache and MySQL/MariaDB available and already configured, so you can develop and test properly on your local machine.

Another option for a quick fix is the [PHP built-in webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) which is available once you've installed PHP, although its features are more limited, it doesn't resemble a real deployed environment as closely, and obviously if you need components such as a database too, you would need to set that up separately yourself.